# How to Alias Enum Fields in Avro schema

Tags: enums, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I would Like to apply aliases to an evolved enum field in my avro schema for backward compatibility.
But After adding aliases to my enum, the schema registry still rejected my schema as incompatible. Can some one please help to see where am I doing wrong? I am Using Avro 1.9.0

The original avro schema:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.example.test",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Employee",
    "doc" : "testing schema",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "EmployeeId",
            "type": "string",
            "doc" : "Employee's Id"
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "EmployeeType",
                "symbols": ["OFFICER", "MANAGER", "DIRECTOR"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have done to evolve the schema is changing its namespace. While the content of the schema remain the same, the enum that was embedded in the Employee schema is implicitly generated with the new namespace `com.example.test.newnamespace`. And that change caused my evolved schema to be backward incompatible.

I tried to add an alias to the evolved enum with the new namespace:

```
{
    "namespace": "com.example.test.newnamespace",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Employee",
    "doc" : "testing schema",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "EmployeeId",
            "type": "string",
            "doc" : "Employee's Id"
        },
        {
            "name": "Type",
            "type": {
                "type": "enum",
                "name": "EmployeeType",
                "aliases": ["com.example.test.EmployeeType"],
                "symbols": ["OFFICER", "MANAGER", "DIRECTOR"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I checks the evolved schema with my schema registry's API, the registry returned `is-compatible = false`.

If I explicitly set my enum's full qualified name to be same as the old namespace `"name": "com.example.test.EmployeeType"`, the evolved schema is compatible.

Where am I doing wrong? I see that the Avro specification does state that enum fields supports aliases:

> Enums
> Enums use the type name "enum" and support the following attributes:
>
> - name: a JSON string providing the name of the enum (required).
> - namespace, a JSON string that qualifies the name;
> - aliases: a JSON array of strings, providing alternate names for this enum (optional).
>
> ... ...

Comment: I think I'm seeing this same, this looks like a bug in the way aliases are applied for FULL compatibility. It looks like aliases are applied in one direction from reader to writer and that they need to be applied in the reverse. See Schema.java#applyAliases around line 1786.

Comment: And apparently that is just how it works, aliases are backwards compatible but not forward compatible.